# Haystack Django Search multiple fields at once

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Using elasticsearch (2.x), django-haystack(2.8.0), drf-haystack (1.8.6) Im building a search. Everything is working fine, except I can't search for multiple fields at the same time. Right now, I can only search for a specific field like (url) `/search/?title=test` and `/search/?text=test`. Each url responds with the right results but just for the specified field.

The desired result is `/search/?q=test` returning both matches for the title and the text to contain the search query "*test*".

Below I added the searchindex for the searched model.

```
class ModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', boost=2.5)
    slug = indexes.CharField(model_attr='slug')
    site_id = indexes.IntegerField()

    def get_model(self):
        return Model

    def prepare_text(self, obj):
        return obj.text

    def prepare_site_id(self, obj):
        return obj.site.id

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        # Used when the entire index for model is updated.
        return self.get_model().objects.all().filter(date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a template where the title and text fields are included.
Example (model_text.txt):

```
{{object.title}}
{{object.text}}
```

Because of this, the text field contains a string with both the fields its value and therefore both get searched when searching like `/search/?text=test`.